# Accessing images of website background and other decorations in WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, web-deployment

I am trying to use some images to decorate my website. But I cannot access those images that placed in WEB-INF folder. My code looks like this:

```
<img id="welcomeGIF" src="/MyCourses/WebContent/WEB-INF/css/welcome.gif " class="ribbon"/>
```

I have no problems accessing these images if I simply put them outside the WEB-INF folder under WebContent directory. I am wondering what I am doing wrong? I am new to web-app development so I am not sure if all the css files should be put in WEB-INF. If so, how do I access them?

Here is the structure of my program:

[image]

Comment: Change the path of image like "./css/welcome.gif". I hope you set web-inf path in .properties file

Answer (score 1):

### the cause:

1. There is a rule that the resource in the WEB-INF directory **can not** be accessed by url (the client)
2. So when the html is loading, the html tag will send a request to the server (to the url `MyCourses/WebContent/WEB-INF/css/welcome.gif`) while the resource is in the WEB-INF directory so you can not access it;

### how to solve

1. the java programmer can access the web-inf directory,so you can use the Dispatch request api

web:

```
<img id="welcomeGIF" src="/MyCourses/getWelcome" class="ribbon"/>
```

java programmer (FileAccess.class)

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/css/welcome.gif").forward(request,response);
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>getGif</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>FileAccess</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>getGif</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/getWelcome</url-pattern>
```

2. place the static file out of the Web-inf directory,(it is ok to do this althought the security is not better than before)
3. if you using the springMvc framework,you can use the  mvc:resources  configuration to set access the static file directly